# How to create an error handling "interceptor" for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, error-handling

So I did a lot of digging around the internet, and I have been unable to come up with the answer to my problem. My goal is that I want to print any errors that are logged to the console into a database. However, I have gone far enough into my project that it would be a pain to go back into my `try...catch...` blocks and edit them with an error extender, or to just create my own function in the catch area.

I wanted to know: is there a specific way to create an error interception in NodeJS? I mean, I assume that whenever an error is logged to the console, the code fires some sort of event, and I guess I am looking for something like:

`process.on(error, async (e) => { // my code here })`

Is that at all possible? Is there a module that will allow me to do this? For context, I am running the latest version of Node/NPM on a headless Ubuntu 18.04 server, and am using `pm2` to control my program processes.

Comment: First off, it's really not a big deal to go find all your `console.log()` statements and modify them to use your own error reporting scheme.  A good editor with grep and replaceAll can make short work of that.  If you're still allergic to that, you can replace/override `console.log()` with your own version that does whatever you want to with the errors.

Comment: *whenever an error is logged to the console, the code fires some sort of event* - No event that I know of.  It sends output to `stdout` or `stderr` which you could intercept if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use middleware at the end of the main file of your app

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
app.use(bodyParser());
...
...

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // Error handler logic
});
```

You can find more about this in the express documentation https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html